# DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security, asp.net-identity

i'm working with custom authentication with asp.net mvc , i'm using Role Provider. i have many to many relation User , Role , UserInRoles .
the error in binding roles values in checkboxs in view

i tried debugging controller create method it return all data in Role table then continue to view in foreach

> error DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.

User Model

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string  UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserInRoles> UserInRoles { get; set; }

    }
```

Role Model

```
public class Role
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserInRoles> UserInRoles { get; set; }


    }
```

UserInRole Model

```
 public class UserInRoles
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
@model AramexOneKnowledge.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
            Select User Role
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles"
                       value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
                @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

expected result display roles in checkbox

Comment: What is in the GetAllRoles function?

Comment: it's a function in Role Provider class @Tony

Comment: this exception because Roles.GetAllRoles() returns array of string and you try to access property name inside it which it not exsits

Comment: can you tell what should i do please ? @AhmedYousif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this exception because `Roles.GetAllRoles()` returns `string[]` and you try to bind  property `Name` inside it which it not exists.

so to overcome this issue you can populate you checkbox list as following

```
ViewBag.RoleId = Roles.GetAllRoles().Select(r => new SelectListItem{Text = r, Value = r});
```

in this case you `SelectListItem` `Value` and `Text` it will be the role name for both of them

Comment: Even better would be to have a function called `GetAllRoles` actually return what one would expect: `Roles` instead of `strings`

Comment: I think no need because he will need only role name to add user to it public static void AddUserToRole (string username, string roleName);

Comment: `@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)`Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.@Ahmed

Comment: all i need is when creating new user you can assign one or more roles to him @AhmedYousif

Comment: you should get selected values from checkbox list while saving

Comment: for this exception Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) change the casting to (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleId